# Is Any need to check the Login Function in every controller page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have followed MVC Pattern In my PHP pages. I have created a controller page for every view page and which will interact with Model page. I have checked the Login of the User on the Top of the every View page. But I have Never checked in Controller page. Since It is possible to anyone enter directly to controller page and may change database content.

So anyone please tell me, is it possible to enter into database through controller page. And whether I need to check Login of the User in controller page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are putting a LOGIN check at the top of every linked page from your controller page (assuming your index.php).

If so, then you don't need to do a login check at the top of every one of your linked pages, only from the index.php. If your login succeeds at the top of your index.php, then you continue on to include your destined view page.

For example (in your index.php)

```
<?php

if ( !$user->checkSession() )
    header('Location: login.php');

if ( $_GET['p'] == 'viewPageName' )
    include('modules/viewPageName.php' )
elseif and so on

?>
```

**EDIT**

Now I have a better understanding of your question.

*Solution 1*:
In your **index.php** (place at top)

```
<?php
define('DIRECT', true);

your login check, etc...
?>
```

In your **other files**, put at the top

```
<?php
if (!defined('DIRECT')) die('No direct access is allowed');

other code, etc...
?>
```

*Solution 2:*
Put an .htaccess file in the folder where all your other files are located, and deny direct access to those files.

Put in the .htaccess the following:

```
deny from all
```

*Solution 3:*
Well, assuming you've defined the $db file at the index.php and have set the class up in your index.php, your other files will return errors because you didn't define your DB class in them.

In other words, if you defined $db = new Database(); in your index.php, your other files will get an error if you try to access directly because $db has yet to be defined in them.

Comment: @ Chris ,yes your assumption is right , But I have intract with database in controller page so If I directly enter to controller not from view page ,then it may spoil the content in database..

Comment: @tomexsans, yes ,Bypassing the index.php,

Comment: @Muthuraj: You have the option to check whether the file is being access directly, as well as another solution. Look at my edit.